# Construct array containing many arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Inside a `foreach` loop, I am returning an array (`$followerPosts`).

```
foreach($myfollowers['entities'] as $myfollower)
{
     $followerPosts=$this->displayPostsAction($myfollower->getFollower());
}
```

I need to have at the end one one big array containing all the `$followerPosts` arrays.

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Thank you for the link @Leri. I tried this but in vain.

Comment: Read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$bigArray = array();
foreach($myfollowers['entities'] as $myfollower)
{
     $followerPosts=$this->displayPostsAction($myfollower->getFollower());
     $bigArray[] =  $followerPosts;
}
```

OR

```
 $bigArray = array();
    foreach($myfollowers['entities'] as $myfollower)
    {
         $bigArray[] =$this->displayPostsAction($myfollower->getFollower());

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an array before the loop, then use array_merge on each iteration

or array_push, it depends on what you want to do

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to put all of them into one array like this:

```
$big = array();
foreach($myfollowers['entities'] as $myfollower)
{
     $big = array_merge($big, $this->displayPostsAction($myfollower->getFollower()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add them to the array.

```
$followerPosts = array()

foreach($myfollowers['entities'] as $myfollower)
{
     //$followerPosts=$this->displayPostsAction($myfollower->getFollower());
     $followerPosts[]=$this->displayPostsAction($myfollower->getFollower());

}

print_r(followerPosts)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the purpose the best tool, I think, is the [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function:

```
$followerPosts = array_map(function($f) {
    return $this->displayPostsAction($f->getFollower());    
}, $myFollowers['entities']);

var_dump($followerPosts);
```